# What is the best method to query azure resource manager data to a legacy interface?

Tags: python, terraform, azure-resource-manager, azure-monitoring

I am trying to fetch azure resource manager data to a legacy monitoring web interface tool. Data required such as 'Resource Name', 'Storage Account Type', 'Size', 'Owner', 'Resource Group', 'Location' etc. I see free python api calls/ Powershell can be used here to query the data from azure monitor. Is there other methods to query these data?Can I use terraform to automate it?

Answer (score 0):

You can call the Azure REST API directly from your webapp, you don't need a backend.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/

Comment: What if I want to render it to a .csv file?

Comment: It is easy enough to convert json -> csv in javascript. https://jsfiddle.net/m788fu63/1/